# Behaviour of sizeof() in C (GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, sizeof

While answering a question on sizeof(), just to see how GCC handles, I wrote the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stddef.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main(int ac, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999) );
    printf("%zu %zu \n", sizeof(int), sizeof(long long));
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled, GCC (4.1.2) issued a warning (as expected):

```
t.c:8:24: warning: integer constant is too large for its type
t.c: In function main:
t.c:8: warning: integer constant is too large for long type
```

And the output is:

```
16
4 8
```

How does GCC say that `sizeof(9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)` is 16 ?! No matter how big `numnber` is, it's always 16 for any integer literal greater than `LLONG_MAX`. On my 64-bit platform `sizeof(long)` is equal to `sizeof(long long)`.

Why does GCC behave this way? Is it some sort of undefined behaviour?!

Comment: By the way, `sizeof` is **not** a function, so it really shouldn't be spelled `sizeof()` since that implies that it is.

Comment: @unwind: You can't have `sizeof long long`, as far as I know. `sizeof(T)` is common and fine.

Comment: @unwind I know sizeof() is not a function but an operator. But I don't see any problem in mentioning sizeof().

Comment: Not to mention that without the parens, it is ambiguous. `sizeof 1 + 1` -> `sizeof(1) + 1` or `sizeof(1 + 1)`?

Comment: It's not *actually* ambiguous: the grammar says how to parse it.  It's a bad idea though, because *people* can't keep it straight. :-) [Trick to keep it straight, btw: if it parsed as (sizeof (1 + 1)), then sizeof(1) + 1 would still be sizeof expr + expr which would still be (sizeof ((1) + 1)).  So it must mean ((sizeof 1) + 1).]

Comment: BTW I think Dennis Ritchie once said that the idea of the `sizeof (` _typename_ `)` syntax was to make it resemble the cast syntax.

Comment: My site is terribly out of date these days.  I need to study C11...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

gcc has a special non-standard type called `__int128`, which is a 128bit (16 byte) integer. So `sizeof(__int128)` will return 16. It seams like your ultra-large constant is treated like this `__int128` type. Consider the following code:

```
typeof(9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999) (*funcptr_a)();
unsigned  __int128 (*funcptr_b)();

void dummy() {
    funcptr_a = funcptr_b;
}
```

If I change any of the types in the declarations of funcptr_a and funcptr_b, the assignment `funcptr_a = funcptr_b;` triggers a warning. I don't get a warning (gcc 4.6.3 on 64-bit Linux) for this variation, therefore I know the type of the large integer constant is `unsigned __int128`.

Btw, with clang 3.0 (also 64-bit Linux) your code outputs

```
8
4 8
```

I'd say this is not undefined but an implementation defined behavior. To quote the C99 standard (Sec. 6.4.4.1, page 56):

> [...] If an integer constant cannot be represented by any type in its list, it may have an
>   extended integer type, if the extended integer type can represent its value. [..]

Comment: One can sometimes also use C11's `_Generic` to somehow confirm the type that a compiler inferred for a particular expression, but your function assignment is a nice trick.

Answer (score 6):

We can ask gcc itself:

```
__typeof__ (9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999) var = 1;
printf("%lld\n", var);
```

```
sizes.c:10:5: warning: format ‘%lld’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__int128’ [-Wformat]
```

So gcc chooses - if supported - the type `__int128` for the too large decimal constant.

Answer (score 1):

What's so mysterious? That's the size of the largest type. You were warned.

All that's guaranteed by the standard is the relative sizes of the various types.

1 == sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)

Comment: On my platform sizeof(long long) is 8, not 16 as shown in the output above. My question is about the 16 given for `sizeof(99999999999999999999999)`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Drat! Should've deleted when it was +3. :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no mystery there. Size of `long` and `long long` are both 8 bytes for GCC 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

gcc probably uses the `long double` type for very big numbers, for which it uses 80 bits on Intel processors. So it probably stores it in a 128-bit number: You should check `sizeof(long double)`.

Note: I explicitly mention gcc because Visual C++ doesn't do that (its `long double` type is the same as `double`).

**Edit:** Turns out it's not `long double` (and according to the standard C99 6.4.4.1 alinea 6 on integer constants (page 56), isn't allowed to be). See CliffordVienna and Daniel Fischer's answers.

Comment: Because it's too big to fit in a `long long`.

Comment: @KingsIndian: The standard doesn't require that.

Comment: @KingsIndian: The C99 standard says (section 6.4.4.1): "*If an integer constant cannot be represented by any type in its list, it may have an
extended integer type, if the extended integer type can represent its value.*"  Extended types are implementation-defined.  There's probably a GCC flag that can disable this sort of thing.